# jquery webmethod call returns whole page html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a website www.arabadukkan.com
I have cascading comboboxes at the top (araç türü->marka->model etc)

I am calling a webmethod to return the results but the result is the html of entire page.
This code works great in my local
WebMethod code :

```
public static string GetMarkas(string selectedId)
{

    var items = Service.DS.GetMarkas().WithCategoryId(selectedId.SayiVer());

    string donen = "<option value=''>Tüm Markalar...</option>";

    foreach (var item in items) donen += string.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", item.id, item.Title);

    return donen;
}
```

I couldnt find any solution. When i look the network tab in chrome i see the GetMarkas response header is "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8"

My script is :

```
function GetCombo(fromCombo, toCombo, method) {
    var veriler = {
        selectedId: $(fromCombo).val()
    };
    $(toCombo).find('option').remove().end().append("<option value='0'>Yükleniyor...</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ResolveUrl('~/wm.aspx/') + method,
        data: $.toJSON(veriler),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $(toCombo).find('option').remove().end().append(msg.d);
            $(toCombo).trigger("change");
        },
        error: function (msg, x, error) {
            alert("Hata Oluştu." + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: "json",`? When returned `dataType` is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I guess u don't require json here..

```
function GetCombo(fromCombo, toCombo, method) {
    var veriler = {
        selectedId: $(fromCombo).val()
    };
    $(toCombo).find('option').remove().end().append("<option value='0'>Yükleniyor...</option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ResolveUrl('~/wm.aspx/') + method,
        data: { selectedId : veriler},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (msg) {
            $(toCombo).find('option').remove().end().append(msg.d);
            $(toCombo).trigger("change");
        },
        error: function (msg, x, error) {
            alert("Hata Oluştu." + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure that you've added necessary web.config entries, specifically httpModules section. Please go through [this](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx)